# Setting missing-method-permissions-deny-access globally in WildFly-8.1

Tags: security, ejb-3.1, wildfly

Im currently using the following `jboss-ejb3.xml` to toggle behaviour for making methods available for all users/roles.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
               impl-version="2.0" version="3.1">
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>false</s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

I like to set this behaviour globally for all my ejbs, without supplying a local `jboss-ejb3.xml` within every module. Unluckily I was unable to find a hint somewhere outside this file.

My question is: is there a file which can set this mode to all included modules within an EAR file?

EDIT: A little addition: http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.1.0.Final/subsystem/ejb3/index.html states it plainly wrong. Default seems to be that `default-mssing-method-permissions-deny-access` is set to `true`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a **`default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access`** attribute in ejb3 subsystem. Just set it to **`false`**.

You can use JBoss CLI for instance:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c /subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name=default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access, value=false)
```

*If you don't use JBOSS_HOME environment variable, then replace the `$JBOSS_HOME` with the full path to your WildFly installation.*